# Linear combination of tensor products of Pauli matrices that produce +/- paired eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, group-theory, symmetry

Eigenvalues of tensor products of Pauli matrices $\sigma_\mu\otimes\sigma_\nu (\mu,\nu\in\{x,y,z\})$ always come in pairs, as a consequence of the fact that eigenvalues of Pauli matrices are $\pm 1$. As a reminder, Pauli matrices are defined to be
$$\sigma_x=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, 
\sigma_y=
\begin{pmatrix}
 0& -i \\ 
i& 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\sigma_z=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Adding in the identity matrix $\sigma_0=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and change letter subscipts $\{x,y,z\}$ into numbers $\{1,2,3\}$ for notational convenience, we use the tensor products of the four matrices to generate $4\times 4$ matrices of the form $\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j$. There are $16$ of them in total.

Now arbitrary linear combinations of them form a $16$-dimensional linear space, and any vector in it must have real eigenvalues since it must be a Hermitian matrix. However, it does not necessarily need to have paired eigenvalues $\pm\lambda$.

My questions is, what are the subspaces that produce paired eigenvalues? I feel it has something to do with group theory since Pauli matrices are generator of $SU(2)$, but I am not very good at representation theory and not sure if there is any theoretical approach/ method to handle problems like this?

I have some computational results. For instance, if my algorithm is not wrong, the dimension of the largest subspace is $10$. If we use a $4\times4$ indicator matrix to indicate which $\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j$ is in the subspace. They are the following, a total of $6$ of them. Here I show one of them

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
which means that any linear combinations of the form
$$a_{03}\sigma_0\otimes\sigma_3+\sum_{i\in\{1,2,3\},j\in\{0,1,2\}}
a_{ij}\sigma_{i}\otimes\sigma_j
$$ have paired eigenvalues.

And it follows immediately that any linear subspaces of those $6$ subspaces again have the property of producing paired eigenvalues. A quick sanity check that the top left element cannot be $1$ in any of these indicator matrices, since $\sigma_0\otimes\sigma_0=\mathbb{I}_4$ does not produce paired eigenvalues $\pm\lambda$.

And that is not the end of the story. It seems that there are other small subspaces that are not subspaces of these $6$ largest ones. For subspaces with dimension $9$, there are $75$ in total, and it means that apart from the $10\times 6=60$ ones that we get immediately from the largest ones, there are $15$ that are new. (It reminds me of the number of generators of $SO(6)$, though they may be totally unrelated.)

We can continue doing this: there are $60$ maximal "paired-eigenvalues" subspaces of dimension $8$. By "maximal" I mean they are not subspaces of any other high-dimensional "paired-eigenvalues" subspaces (i.e., they cannot be extended). For dimension $7$, there is no maximal one. For $6$, there are $17$...

One possible problem in the results I get above is that I am only considering linear subspaces of the form $a_{ij}\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j$ (summed over $i$ and $j$ with arbitrary $a_{ij}$). There are $2^{16}$ of them and correspond 1-to-1 to indicator matrices. There might be other subspaces that have this "paired eigenvalues" property with fine-tuned coefficients $a_{ij}$ that cannot be represented by an indicator matrix.

For instance, the vector $(\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x+\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y)$ also forms a $1$-dimensional subspace, but it cannot be represented by our indicator matrix.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Do you know about the [Dirac matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices)?

Comment: @Shaun I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @KurtG. Not really. I know them, but am not very familar with their properties.

Comment: I mean, don't do stuff like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnJNi.png); use $\rm\LaTeX$ instead.

Comment: @Apocalypse They are part of the space you are looking at and their eigenvalues are $\pm 1\,.$ I'd get familiar with them before doing that type of research.

Comment: @Shaun I see what you mean. Those matrices are computer-generated and so I spare my effort of texting them out if they they don't hinder reader's understanding of the problem.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks, actually I tried, but it brings me to even more advanced stuff like Clifford algebra and I have spent two days on it (with learning literally nothing, sigh)

Comment: Pictures like that aren't user-friendly and, generally, we advise against them here.

Comment: @Apocalypse . To check that the $\gamma$-matrices are tensor product of Pauli matrices and have eigenvalues like them you do not have to deal with the Clifford algebra. Honestly: what is advanced is your OP. There is a well-known solution now and you give up ?

Comment: @Shaun I have deleted the pictures. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @KurtG. It is not hard for me to check $\gamma$ matrices are tensor products of Pauli matrices, but only knowing this certainly doesn't mean I understand $\gamma$ matrices very well. To have a deeper understanding of it, I was lead to Clifford algebra a few days ago, but I have spent days on it and the progress is extremely slow...

Comment: @KurtG. For instance, it is obvious that every $\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j$ has +/- paired eigenvalues except for $i=j=0$ which gives the identity matrix $\mathbb{I}$, but there are only $4$ (or $5$, if we include $\gamma^5$) $\gamma$-matrices. I know these 4 or 5 matrices are part of the 15 candidates, but why do we choose those particular 4 or 5 to be our $\gamma$-matrices? I don't understand why the choice appears naturally (I believe it comes from more advanced stuff).